# Nextjs navigating around is too slow, SSR specifically

Tags: reactjs, performance, optimization, next.js, server-side-rendering

Obviously this question has been asked before but the answers fail to help me.

My problem is server side rendering takes way too long, Navigating from page to page takes like 2.5-4 and sometimes 10 seconds. All I do is 2 queries to the database using prisma and few simple necessary functions.

Im aware that images are a big factor in performance, but despite using a cdn and optimizing images to the maximum it still isn't enough.

My question is how will nextjs handle heavy requests and lots of data in a real big website if it can't handle my pathetic website?.

Please keep in mind that this is my first app using nextjs and im certain that im missing something out.

Here's the link to the site, navigate around and see for yourself, I've added a progress bar in hopes of making it less painful but still the old "smooth react navigation" isn't there.

https://elvito-property.netlify.app/

Link to the repo

https://github.com/VitoMedlej/elvito-property

And ofcourse here is the full code I use to fetch the data using getServerSideProps

`
const isCategoryValid = (categoryQuery : string) => {
let categories = ["apartment", "villa", "comercial", "land", "chalet"]

```
if (categories.includes(categoryQuery)) {
    return categoryQuery
}
return undefined
```

}`

`const isPurposeValid = (purposeQuery : string) => { if (purposeQuery === 'for-sale' || purposeQuery === 'for-rent') { return purposeQuery } return undefined }`

`const GetTotalCount = async(type?: string, purpose?: string) => {
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

```
const totalCount = await prisma
    .properties
    .count({
        where: {
            type,
            purpose
        }
    })
return totalCount || 0
```

}`

`export async function getServerSideProps({query} : any) {

```
const select = {
    id: true,
    type: true,
    bathrooms: true,
    rooms: true,
    price: true,
    propertySize: true,
    images: true,
    title: true,
    location: true,
    purpose: true,
    currency: true,
    description: true
}

const itemsPerPage = 9
const prisma = new PrismaClient()
const purpose = isPurposeValid(`${query.purpose}`)
const type = isCategoryValid(`${query.category}`)
try {
    const currentPage = query.page || 0;
    const totalCount = await GetTotalCount(type, purpose) || 0
    const totalPages = Math.round(totalCount / itemsPerPage)
    let skip = (currentPage * itemsPerPage) || undefined
    if (currentPage > totalPages || currentPage < 0) 
        skip = 0

    let data : any = await prisma
        .properties
        .findMany({
            skip,
            take: itemsPerPage,
            where: {
                purpose,
                type
            },
            select
        })
    // just returning the first image because that's all I need, wish prisma provided
    // an easier way to do this but oh well
    data.forEach((item : any) => {
        item.images
            ? item.images = item.images[0]
            : ''
    })

    // just a way to deal with bigints
    bigInt_To_Number(data)

    return {
        props: {
            results: data,
            totalCount
        }
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log('err 1.4: ', err);
    return {props: {}}
} finally {
    await prisma.$disconnect()
}
```

}
`

Comment: In checking your netlify site, it seems the application stalls to paint until this is responded to `https://elvito-property.netlify.app/_next/data/15WwmL4sQPSQx0zAq5UJf/real-estate-and-homes/properties.json?purpose=for-sale&category=properties&page=1` - It consistently takes 2+ seconds on client side navigation - How is properties.json generated?

Comment: `properties.json` is the result of running `getServerSideProps` for the `/real-estate-and-homes/properties` page. The long load times are due to what happens inside it - I'd recommend properly debugging the `getServerSideProps` to see where the bottleneck comes from.

Comment: "All I do is 2 queries to the database" Sequentially? if so, then you twice incur the cost of the latency between the Vercel serverless/edge functions and the database.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I can suggest is to find a way to switch to get static props or get static paths

Also I hope this discussion can also help you to find the preferred solution for you

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/32243

Answer (score 0):

In Next.js, navigating around the application with Server-Side Rendering (SSR) can sometimes be slow, even in version 12. However, it appears that this issue has been addressed and improved upon in Next.js version 13.

If you're experiencing slow SSR navigation in Next.js 12 or earlier, consider trying the following approach to potentially improve performance:

Instead of using `getServerSideProps`, you can use `getInitialProps` for your data fetching needs. This change might lead to a significant improvement in navigation speed.

Here's an example of how you can use `getInitialProps`:

```
import React from 'react';

function Page({ data }) {
  // Your component rendering logic here
}

Page.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  // Fetch your data here
  const data = await fetchData();

  return { data };
};

export default Page;
```

By making this switch, you may notice a noticeable boost in navigation performance, particularly when dealing with SSR in Next.js. However, keep in mind that the exact impact may vary depending on your specific use case and application requirements.

Please ensure that you're using Next.js version 13 or later to take full advantage of any performance improvements and enhancements made in those releases.